# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run a cnn model for some classification but I am getting the following error:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'`

These are the packages that I installed:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import time
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import csv
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout , Flatten, Dense
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

I already changed `keras.models import Sequential` to `tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential` but this also does not seem to help.

This is the output that I am receiving:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5c123eb040bc> in <module>
     50 
     51 model = Sequential()
---> 52 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape=(99,13,1),activation='relu'))
     53 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
     54 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape=(99,13,1),activation='relu'))

/opt/anaconda3/envs/MlChallenge/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/opt/anaconda3/envs/MlChallenge/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
    488             kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
    489             bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
--> 490             **kwargs)
    491 
    492     def get_config(self):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/MlChallenge/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in __init__(self, rank, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
    103                  bias_constraint=None,
    104                  **kwargs):
--> 105         super(_Conv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    106         self.rank = rank
    107         self.filters = filters

/opt/anaconda3/envs/MlChallenge/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    130         if not name:
    131             prefix = self.__class__.__name__
--> 132             name = _to_snake_case(prefix) + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
    133         self.name = name
    134 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/MlChallenge/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     72     """
     73     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 74     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     75     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     76         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

I am using Tensorflow 2.0 and keras 2.2.4, does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here:

1. You are mixing imports between `tf.keras` and `keras`, this is not supported, pick one package and stick with it
2. Keras 2.2.4 does not support TensorFlow 2.0, for this you need to either upgrade Keras to version 2.3.x, or downgrade TensorFlow to version 1.x.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
For the first issue: I deleted the tensorflow.python and thus only use the keras package now.
For the second issue: I downgraded tensorflow to version 1.1 but now i get the following error: `TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'` which I did not get before.